# Replace "?*" with "*" but not "?+" with "*+"

Tags: search, sed, replace

I have the following string in a file:

```
?*TEST?*
?+
```

Now i want the `?*` to be replaced with an asterisks `*`. The file should be like that after the replacement:

```
*TEST*
?+
```

I tested a few ways but cannot find the answer. The problem is that every sed command either also replaces `?*` with `**` or nothing.

Comment: What have you tried?  It seems that `sed -e '/TEST/{s/?\*/*?/; s/\*?/?*/; }'` does what you want, but you really haven't given enough detail.

Comment: You say you want to replace `?*` with `*`, but your example replaces `*?` with `?*`. Which do you want?

Comment: Could you clarify the output after replacement?

Comment: I corrected the in- and output. Sorry about that. It was too late.

Answer (score 0):

One of these should match. In any case `?+` remains intact.

```
$ echo "$a"
*?TEST?*
?+
*?TEST?*
?+
$ echo "$a" |sed 's/[?][*]/*/g'
*?TEST*
?+
*?TEST*
?+
$ echo "$a" |sed -E 's/([*])([?])/\2\1/g'
?*TEST?*
?+
?*TEST?*
?+
$ echo "$a" |sed 's/[?][*]/***???/g'
*?TEST***???
?+
*?TEST***???
?+
```